# Switch statement not working as expected

Tags: php

I have the follwing code:

```
switch ((int)$_GET["loanprovider"]) {
    case ((int)$_GET["loanprovider"] > 1):
        $sql_loanprovider1a = " l.id in (select la.loanid from loan_approvals la where la.bankid = ".$_GET["loanprovider"].") and";
        $sql_loanprovider1b = " l.loanid in (select la.loanid from loan_approvals la where la.bankid = ".$_GET["loanprovider"].") and";
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

If i run the page without setting LOANPROVIDER in the URL, the SWITCH still enters the first case and not the DEFAULT. How come??

/Bob

Comment: The problem you experience is that the result of an expression results in a TRUE or FALSE value (1 or 0).

Therefore your expression is testing if (int)$_GET["loanprovider"]) = 1, or 0, as the case may be.

Correct your logic, and get the results you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would first check if $_GET["loanprovider"] is set because if you don't set loanprovider in the url it will be undefined and undefined does not have to be "0" it can be something else. In this case it would be probably some value that makes your statement ((int)$_GET["loanprovider"] > 1): true.

The correct code would be:

```
if (isset((int)$_GET["loanprovider"]))
{
  switch ((int)$_GET["loanprovider"]) {
    case ((int)$_GET["loanprovider"] > 1):
        $sql_loanprovider1a = " l.id in (select la.loanid from loan_approvals la where la.bankid = ".$_GET["loanprovider"].") and";
        $sql_loanprovider1b = " l.loanid in (select la.loanid from loan_approvals la where la.bankid = ".$_GET["loanprovider"].") and";
        break;
    default:
        break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Interesting to note that `case ((int)$_GET["loanprovider"] > 1)` returns a warning msg if not set, but still returns a positive!

Answer (score 2):

The explanation is quite simple:

```
var_dump( (int)$_GET["loanprovider"]  );
var_dump( (int)$_GET["loanprovider"] > 1 );
```

The output is:

```
int(0)
bool(false)
```

They're both the same (the integer 0 (zero) is considered as `FALSE`), and case 1 will always get executed  if the query parameter `loanprovider` is empty.

Refer to the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) for more information.

---

And, to actually fix the issue, use [`isset()`](http://php.net/isset). It's also a good idea to declare variables and store values if you need to re-use it later.

The following looks neater, in my opinion, and it works (tested):

```
if(isset($_GET['loanprovider'])) 
{
    $value = (int)$_GET["loanprovider"];
    switch ($value) {
        case ($value > 1):
            $sql_loanprovider1a = " l.id in (select la.loanid from loan_approvals la where la.bankid = ".$_GET["loanprovider"].") and";
            $sql_loanprovider1b = " l.loanid in (select la.loanid from loan_approvals la where la.bankid = ".$_GET["loanprovider"].") and";
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

For debugging the issue, you can always use [`var_dump`](http://php.net/var_dump).

Answer (score 0):

I'm no PHP expert, but I think your redundant use of loanprovider in the switch statement is a clue. I think if you don't set loanprovider you will have an empty value of some sort, which goes in the parameter to switch, and then you use a similar value in the case. assume `(int)$_GET["loanprovider"]` is 0. Then the expression `(int)$_GET["loanprovider"] > 1` will also return 0 because 0 is not greater than 1. What you end up with is essentially:

```
switch (0) {
case 0:
  // your code
  break;
default:
  break;
}
```

Because 0 == 0, you end up in the first case.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but request to try it (though the coding is for >1)

But it will be wrong for negative value.

```
switch (intval($_GET["loanprovider"])) {
    case 0:
        break;
    case 1:
        break;
    default:
        $sql_loanprovider1a = " l.id in (select la.loanid from loan_approvals la where la.bankid = ".$_GET["loanprovider"].") and";
        $sql_loanprovider1b = " l.loanid in (select la.loanid from loan_approvals la where la.bankid = ".$_GET["loanprovider"].") and";
        break;
```